# How to subscribe to the ApplicationStartup event in Nancyfx?

Tags: nancy

I'm building an extension to Nancy and I'm not really sure where to hook into Nancy's ApplicationStartup event.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you need to hook into, for what purpose. Question is too vague.

Comment: I'm building a asset optimization library to minifiy js and css files. Wanted the optimization to happen at app startup but don't know how to hook into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run some code automatically when your library is installed, then you need to inherit the Nancy class `IApplicationStartup` and write your implementation.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/IApplicationStartup.cs

For example, for Nancy.Raygun I do the following:

```
public class NancyRaygunRegistration : IApplicationStartup
{
    private static readonly RaygunClient Client;

    static NancyRaygunRegistration()
    {
        var apiKey = RaygunSettings.Settings.ApiKey;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKey))
        {
            apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nr.apiKey"];
        }

        if (apiKey == null) return;

        Client = new RaygunClient(apiKey);
    }

    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        if (Client == null) return;

        var raygunItem = new PipelineItem<Func<NancyContext, Exception, Response>>("Raygun", (context, exception) =>
        {
            Client.SendInBackground(context, exception);

            return null;
        });

        pipelines.OnError.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(raygunItem);
    }
}
```

Nancy will automatically find all implementations of `IAppliationStartup` and run them.

Other things to consider:

`IRegistrations` https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/IRegistrations.cs

`IRequestStartup` https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/IRequestStartup.cs

`IPipelines` https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/IPipelines.cs